encryption in logstash pipeline
I have below code in java, which encrypting input data using AES
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");

        if (data == null)
            return encryptedText;

        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

        // get IV
        byte[] iv = getRandomNonce(12);
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));
        // encrypted data:
        byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        // prefix IV and Salt to cipher text
        byte[] cipherTextWithIvSalt = ByteBuffer.allocate(iv.length + salt.length() + encryptedBytes.length).put(iv)
                .put(salt.getBytes()).put(encryptedBytes).array();

        encryptedText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherTextWithIvSalt);

I have logstash pipeline where for encryption i'm trying with below code in ruby, however it is not working
  ruby {
code => "
  require 'openssl'
  require 'base64'

  password = 'secret_key'
  salt = 'random_salt'
  iterations = 65536
  key_len = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm').key_len
  key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac(password, salt, iterations, key_len, 'sha256')

  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm')
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = key
  iv = Random.new.bytes(12)
  encrypted = cipher.update(event.get('secret')) + cipher.final
  length=iv.length+salt.length+encrypted.length
  
    // buffer =IO::Buffer.new(10)// not working
    
    
  encrypted_text = Base64.encode64(buffer).strip

  event.set('message_encrypted', encrypted_text)
"
add_field => {
      "new_secret" => "%{[message_encrypted]}"
    }

}
Can someone help to figure out the missing part in the code?

How isn't it working?

Which version of Ruby is being used here?

The issue seems to be that there's no implicit string conversion on your Buffer instance. If I run your program as is, I see:

no implicit conversion of IO::Buffer into String

Explicitly calling to_s on the instance as it's encoded solves the problem, though.
require "openssl"
require "base64"

password = "secret_key"
salt = "random_salt"
iterations = 65536
key_len = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-256-gcm").key_len
key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac(password, salt, iterations, key_len, "sha256")

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-256-gcm")
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key
iv = Random.new.bytes(12)
encrypted = cipher.update(event.get("secret")) + cipher.final
length = iv.length + salt.length + encrypted.length

buffer = IO::Buffer.new(10)
# It looks like you're using JRuby, so you may need to do the following instead:
# require 'java'
# buffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(10)

encrypted_text = Base64.encode64(buffer.to_s).strip
puts encrypted_text # IzxJTzo6QnVmZmVyIDB4MDAwMDU1NjhjN2Q1NDViMCsxMCBJTlRFUk5BTD4=

event.set('message_encrypted', encrypted_text)

In case it's relevant, this was run using Ruby 3.3.0.

I'm getting following error with use of IO Buffer-> Ruby exception occurred: uninitialized constant IO::Buffer {:class=>"NameError", :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyModule.java:4324:in const_missing'", "(ruby filter code):19:in b

@ManojSingh I've updated my answer based on the reference to JRuby in that exception.
